# Finding area under curve using integrals.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

For the curve with equation $\frac{(3X + 1)}{\sqrt{X}}$ I am asked to find the area under curve from X = 1 to X = 2.

Integrating the expression I obtained, $\frac{2X^3}{2} + 2\sqrt{X}$

Applying limits the value for area under curve I obtained is 11 unlike my manual stating the expected answer $6\sqrt{2} - 4$.

Comment: I don't know about "applying limits"... the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus should let you take $$F(b) - F(a)$$

Comment: (I verified the manual's solution using the F.T.C.)

Comment: For the curve, I am asked to find the area under it from x=1 to x=2

Answer (score 2):

Your integral is (from what I think I can see due to formatting issues) correct.

$$I = \int \frac{3x+1}{\sqrt{x}} dx = 2(x^{\frac{3}{2}}+\sqrt{x}) = 2\sqrt{x}(x+1).$$

Now simply plugging in limits of integration, you have

$$\left[ 2\sqrt{x}(x+1) \right]_1^2 = (2\sqrt{2}\times 3) - (2\sqrt{1}\times 2) = 6\sqrt2 - 4$$

as your manual states.